# do hazelcast have igmp support?

Tags: hazelcast

Does hazelcast support IGMP?
if so, what version of IGMP version 1,2 or 3. (IGMP leave,joint, etc)

Does hazelcast support (igmp snooping) this is enabled default in
many cisco networks.

Thank you.

Comment: Whad do you exactly mean by asking if it supports it?

Comment: yes. I am asking if IGMP version 1,2 or 3 is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast relies on the `MulticastSocket` API, which does not explicitly mention IGMP as the underlying protocol. The exact code and API calls used can be inspected in the [MulticastService](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/internal/cluster/impl/MulticastService.java) class.